# regex split image src asp.net

Tags: regex, string, image, split, src

Hi i got a question to ask u all

Here is my codding

```
string testing="<img src=\"cid:tmpImage.gif\">,cdefetfdgfdg ,ewrewrewr,<img src=\"cid:tmpImage1.gif\">,<img src=\"cid:tmpImage2.gif\">,<img src=\"cid:tmpImage3.gif\">,<img src=\"cid:tmpImage4.gif\">";
    string[] splitText = Regex.Split(testing, @"(<img([^>]+)>)");
```

How can i get the split text something like :

```
 1. <img src=\"cid:tmpImage.gif\">
 2. <img src=\"cid:tmpImage1.gif\">  
 3. <img src=\"cid:tmpImage2.gif\">
```

Thank for anyone who help me :)

Comment: do you really want the escaped double quotes (\") in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Regex.Split(testing, @"(\<img([^>]+)\>)")`